# ¿Como enviar información de variables a Arduino desde una app flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, arduino

Tengo que hacer en unas cajas de texto se guarden en variables, pero esa información será enviada a un Arduino uno. Y tambien el arduino nos devolvera otros valores de un sensor y desplegarlos en la pantalla flutter

Comment: Lo primero es aprender a programar Arduinos. Luego aprender a comunicarlo vía Serial con un PC (Python, probablemente). Ahi ya tienes la información en el PC (y puedes enviar del PC al Arduino); el resto es colocarla donde Android pueda tomarla.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.